# What would be the shape of a candle in a zero gravity environment?

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity

What would be the exact shape of a burning candle if it is placed in a zero gravity environment...I am not able to determine the way the fire and the candle aligns.. 
Please help me out!

Comment: This link ives a good qualitative description https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zdD7lfB0Fs